# Create a key object

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a text box in a form and I want all keys preset in this text box should have the SHIFT key applied

There is a property shift on key down on all keys e.shift true/false but I got A error that it's a read only property

So what I will try to do is to create a new key object of the preset key and then I will try to change it and then to sand back the key object for the preset key but I don't know how to make it

If anyone can help me please !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the [`TextBox.CharacterCasing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.charactercasing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.  You can set that to force the text in a TextBox to be all upper case or all lower case.  [CharacterCasing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.charactercasing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be Normal (the default), Lower where all text will be lowercase, and Upper where all text will be uppercase.

You can set this in the Forms Designer or in code as below:

```
textBox1.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
```

Comment: I understand what you men but my problem is that I need the special symbol that comes with the preset shift not the upper case